# Full viewport height scaling div just css no js... Possible?

Tags: css, height, scaling, viewport

Ok, I'm trying to get a div to scale and the height is always the height of the viewport. I'm going to link to my examples as it needs some explaining.

www.madmediablitz.com/tv/precentdemo.html

The link above is the closest I've come to a solution and I'm hoping that someone here will find it simple to fix. What I want to happen is the tv to always be the height of the viewport (to a degree, min-height:~400px; max-height:~700px;). The code that I used there is based on http://www.alistapart.com/articles/creating-intrinsic-ratios-for-video/.

www.madmediablitz.com/tv/precentdemo_alt.html

This one is what I DON'T want to happen. IF you resize your window you will see it doesn't scale proportionally.

I've been trying both of these for about 2 days now and I haven't been able to get it to work. I'm literally praying for help as I think, this isn't too complicated.

Comment: Also, Ignore the fact that the tv doesn't line up 100%, that is my slicing error.

Answer (score 43):

Please see this:
[http://stanhub.com/how-to-make-div-element-100-height-of-browser-window-using-css-only/](https://web.archive.org/web/20160507062921/https://stanhub.com/how-to-make-div-element-100-height-of-browser-window-using-css-only)

```
<div id="welcome">
   your content on screen 1
</div>

<div id="projects">
   your content on screen 2
</div>
div#welcome {
    height: 100vh;
    background: black;
}

div#projects {
    height: 100vh;
    background: yellow;
}
```

That's it.

Comment: If anyone is reading this, this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Be aware, this will not work in Andorid 4.3 or lower, Opera mini, IE8 or lower, and is buggy in iOS 7.1 or lower. See: http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units

Comment: Please add some explanation of why this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [answer] for more information.

Answer (score 12):

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Read [this](http://www.dave-woods.co.uk/?p=144) article.

Comment: Please add some explanation of why this code helps the OP, in the answer itself, not on a third-party site. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [answer] for more information.

Answer (score 11):

You can use absolute positioning in a quite surprising way I surmise:

```
div#element {
  position: relative;
}

img.vertical {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; // no need for px or em 
  bottom: 0;
}
```

A compliant browser should try to respect both the top and bottom directives, actually managing a full height.